# Filter Pandas DataFrame using GroupBy with Count of Certain Value

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like to filter a pandas DataFrame to rows where that particular row's group has a minimum count of a specific column value.

For example, return only the rows/groups of df where the ['c2','c3'] group has at least 2 rows with 'c1' value of 1:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[0,1,0,1,1,0], 'c2':[0,0,0,1,1,1], 'c3':[0,0,0,1,1,1]})
```

The result should return only the rows with indices 3,4,5 since only the [c2,c3] = [1,1] group has at least 2 rows with 'c1' value of 1.

```
df.groupby(['c2','c3']).filter(lambda x: x['c1'].count() >= 2)
```

does not return the required result. I need the count to apply specifically to the count of 1s, not just any value of 'c1'.

The following works but I am not sure how to make it more pythonic:

```
s = df.groupby(['c2','c3']).apply(lambda x: x[x['c1']==1].count() >= 2).all(axis=1)
df = df.reset_index().set_index(['c2','c3']).loc[s[s].index].reset_index().set_index(['index'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `groupby` + `transform` to sum a Boolean Series, which we use to mask the original DataFrame.

```
m = df['c1'].eq(1).groupby([df['c2'], df['c3']]).transform('sum').ge(2)

# Alterntively assign the column
#m = df.assign(to_sum = df.c1.eq(1)).groupby(['c2', 'c3']).to_sum.transform('sum').ge(2) 

df.loc[m]
#   c1  c2  c3
#3   1   1   1
#4   1   1   1
#5   0   1   1
```

With filter, `count` is not the correct logic. Use `==` (or `.eq()`) to check where `'c1'` is equal to the specific value. Sum the Boolean Series and check that there are at least 2 such occurrences per group for your filter.

```
df.groupby(['c2','c3']).filter(lambda x: x['c1'].eq(1).sum() >= 2)
#   c1  c2  c3
#3   1   1   1
#4   1   1   1
#5   0   1   1
```

---

While not noticeable for a small DataFrame, `filter` with a `lambda` is horribly slow as the number of groups grows. `transform` is fast:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':np.random.randint(1,100,1000), 'c2':np.random.randint(1,100,1000), 
                   'c3':np.random.choice([1,0], 1000)})

%%timeit
m = df['c1'].eq(1).groupby([df.c3, df.c3]).transform('sum').ge(2)
df.loc[m]
#5.21 ms ± 15.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df.groupby(['c2','c3']).filter(lambda x: x['c1'].eq(1).sum() >= 2)
#124 ms ± 714 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Very interesting approach. I was not aware that even if you changed the value of 1 in 'c1' to 'a' that ````df['c1'].eq('a').sum()```` would "count" the number of True values. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the .eq() returns a Boolean Series, and when you apply an operation like `.sum` it coerces True to 1 and False to 0.

Comment: @user7101631 In that case I'm grouping a Series by the DataFrame columns, so the syntax is a bit different, and requires the grouping columns to be passed separately. If you need to use many columns in the original DataFrame, then I'd create the column you need to sum, with `.assign`, and then pass a list of the columns you need to group on. `m = df.assign(to_sum = df.c1.eq(1)).groupby(['c2', 'c3']).to_sum.transform('sum').ge(2)`

Answer (score 1):

May using `groupby` + `merge`

```
s=df.groupby(['c2','c3']).c1.sum().ge(2)
s[s].index.to_frame().reset_index(drop=True).merge(df,how='left')
   c2  c3  c1
0   1   1   1
1   1   1   1
2   1   1   0
```